# making the enter key choose random text

Tags: html

i'm new to this website and new to html as well, so please forgive me for any mistakes...

I have this code here:

```
 <textarea type="text" rows="1" name="" cols="30" class="BodyCopy" value="" style="border: none" onclick="pictureChange()" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { quotes(); return false;">
```

It was working fine earlier today, but i changed something, and now i can't seem to be able to figure out whats wrong with it! This code is supposed to make it so you hit the enter key instead of a button, and it's supposed to display random text (which i have figured out in the <head> of my website). It displays the textbox just fine, but when I hit enter it just goes down & keeps typing. It doesn't do what it should.

Could someone please go through the code above to try and find out why it isn't functioning properly? Thank you so much!

Comment: You are missing a closing braces } for onKeydown if (event.keyCode == 13) { quotes(); return false;}"

Comment: It works beautifully. I feel so stupid now; i sat looking at it for a long while trying to figure out what i did wrong!

Comment: @iCode Do you think you could make it so the keyboard would dismiss when the user hit enter?

Comment: I mean like on an apple device...

Comment: So you want nothing to happen when enter key is pressed?

Comment: No no no.... I would like it to generate the random text, but i would like the keyboard to dismiss right afterwards. And by this i mean a mobile device, like an iphone or ipad or something.

Comment: @iCode (i forgot to tag you)

Comment: Try this, if (event.keyCode == 13) { quotes();document.activeElement.blur(); return false;}

Comment: @iCodeThat works perfectly! I was researching and had found the same thing, but i put it in the wrong spot! Thank you.